# String.fromCharCode doesn't show anything for 'Enter' in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a JavaScript calculator and trying to map key press events to the appropriate button event. So when a user presses 1, then `$('#one').click` will get triggered and so on. My code basically does this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {

    var keyPressed = (String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    switch(keyPressed) {
        case '1':
            $('#one').trigger('click');
            break;
        case '2':
        // etc.....
    }
}
```

When I press enter, I get 13 as the char code from `e.which`. However, when I pass 13 to `String.fromCharCode` I get an empty string (actually, I'm not sure if it's an empty string or a string with a space, I can't quite see). Can someone please explain why this is happening? How can I capture the 'Enter' key press in the logic of my case statement (I know I can use an object and map the keys/keypressstrings to values/buttonIDs to avoid the case), if possible at all?

Comment: Character code `13` represents a carriage return, a type of whitespace – also represented by the escape sequence, `'\r'`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? Also, is there a resource which represents all characters fromCharCode will return?

Comment: why is it needed to capture it in switch case only, otherwise its simply `if(e.which ==13){}`

Comment: @daremkd Just search "ascii table" and you will see the basic ones.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but today we can use some other properties of this event.

For example, if the user press the number '1' key then:

```
event.charCode || event.keyCode || event.which // will give us 49
event.key // will give us "1"
event.code // will give us DigitOne
```

Running example:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");

input.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  console.clear();
  const {key, code, charCode, keyCode, which} = event;
  console.log("key - ",key);
  console.log("code - ",code);
  console.log("charCode - ",charCode);
  console.log("keyCode - ",keyCode);
  console.log("which - ",which);
  input.select();
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" value="" placeholder="type me"  />
```

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)